# Selenium Grid with Ant sequential + parallel execution

Tags: ant, selenium, parallel-processing, selenium-grid

I am trying to run the selenium tests with selenium grid 2 set up. My tests are more dependent . I have to well-define my sequential run & parallel run. Attaching my build.xml file for ref. Inside sequential node I have many parallel nodes with different targets. I am facing inconsistency issues in running this build.xml.

Some times it picks up the targets of 2nd parallel node & sometimes its not. It is not giving error also. I tried running ant command in verbose mode, still not getting ant exceptions.

Will be glad if someone helps in this regard.

```
<target name="startServerRC" depends="startServerhub">
        <echo>Starting Selenium Server...</echo>
        <java jar="${lib.dir}/selenium-server-standalone.jar" fork="true" spawn="true">
            <arg line="-port 5555"/>
            <arg line="-log log.txt"/>  
            <arg line="-firefoxProfileTemplate"/>
            <arg value="${lib.dir}/ff_profile"/>
            <arg line="-userExtensions"/>
                <arg value="${lib.dir}/user-extensions.js"/>
            <arg line="-role node"/>
            <arg line="-hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register "/>
            <arg line="-maxSession 10"/>
            <arg line="-maxInstances=10"/>
        </java>
    </target>

        <!-- Initialization -->
    <target name="init" depends="startServerRC" >
        <echo>Initlizing...</echo>
        <delete dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Complies the java files -->
    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <echo>Compiling...</echo>
        <javac 
            debug="true" 
            srcdir="${src.dir}" 
            destdir="${classes.dir}"   
            classpathref="classpath" />
    </target>

    <target name="CItarget">    
        <sequential>
            <antcall target="compile"/>
            <parallel> 
              <antcall target="run"/>
              <antcall target="run_PSDATA"/>
            </parallel>
            <parallel> 
                <antcall target="run_PreData"/> 
                <antcall target="run_DFPPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_AdTechPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_AppnexusPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_FTPPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_OASPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_GDFPPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_FreewheelPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_ThirdPartyPulls"/> 
            </parallel>
            <parallel>
        <antcall target="run_PostData"/> 
                <antcall target="run_Sales"/> 
            </parallel>
            <parallel>
                <antcall target="run_Administration"/> 
                <antcall target="run_E2EPartner360"/> 
                <antcall target="run_Sales"/> 
                <antcall target="run_Finance"/> 
                <antcall target="run_Loaders"/> 
                <antcall target="run_Accounts"/> 
                <antcall target="run_Adops"/> 
            </parallel>
            <parallel>
                <antcall target="run_Alerts"/> 
                <antcall target="run_CustomFields"/> 
            </parallel>
            <antcall target="stop-selenium"/>
       </sequential>
    </target>
```

Thanks in advance
Anjana

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ant - continue the target execution ,even if one target completes for selenium automation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117370/ant-continue-the-target-execution-even-if-one-target-completes-for-selenium-a)

Answer (score 1):

Try [QAF (formerly ISFW)](http://qmetry.github.io/qaf) where you can run test parallel with/without use of grid.
In Your case following config file can fulfill your requirement:

```
<suite name="Sample Test Automation" verbose="0" parallel="tests">
<test name="Set1" > 
    <parameter name="selenium.server" value="server1"/>
    <parameter name="selenium.port" value="port"/>

    <!-- group or class or package entry as per testNG standard 
     -->    
    <classes>
    <class name="qualified name of class"></class>
    </classes>>     
</test>


<test name="set2" > 
    <parameter name="selenium.server" value="server2"/>
    <parameter name="selenium.port" value="port"/>

    <!-- <packages>
        <package name="package name" />
    </packages> 
     -->    
    <classes>
    <class name="qualified name of class"></class>
    </classes>
</test> 

</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to use tesng or junit to manager parallel testing instead of doing it directly in Build.xml.

here is a good tutorial on configuring testng, Ant and selenium grid :

http://technologyandleadership.com/six-steps-for-complete-test-automation-with-selenium-grid/