# Ant - continue the target execution ,even if one target completes for selenium automation

Tags: ant, selenium, selenium-grid

Is there a way to cause Ant to not quit even if one of a target completes?

For instance, several targets may execute, and if the first one stops,selenium will freeze.All the other testcases which are running parallel in other target stops.

How to make ant to continue executing other targets,even if one completes.

I tried giving `-k` at target level , but no use. We have `failonerror` set to true .Does that matter?

Here is my build file :

```
<target name="startServerRC" depends="startServerhub">
        <echo>Starting Selenium Server...</echo>
        <java jar="${lib.dir}/selenium-server-standalone.jar" fork="true" spawn="true">
            <arg line="-port 5555"/>
            <arg line="-log log.txt"/>  
            <arg line="-firefoxProfileTemplate"/>
            <arg value="${lib.dir}/ff_profile"/>
            <arg line="-userExtensions"/>
                <arg value="${lib.dir}/user-extensions.js"/>
            <arg line="-role node"/>
            <arg line="-hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register "/>
            <arg line="-maxSession 10"/>
            <arg line="-maxInstances=10"/>
        </java>
    </target>

        <!-- Initialization -->
    <target name="init" depends="startServerRC" >
        <echo>Initlizing...</echo>
        <delete dir="${classes.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Complies the java files -->
    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <echo>Compiling...</echo>
        <javac 
            debug="true" 
            srcdir="${src.dir}" 
            destdir="${classes.dir}"   
            classpathref="classpath" />
    </target>

    <target name="CItarget">    
        <sequential>
            <antcall target="compile"/>
            <parallel> 
              <antcall target="run"/>
              <antcall target="run_PSDATA"/>
            </parallel>
            <parallel> 
                <antcall target="run_PreData"/> 
                <antcall target="run_DFPPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_AdTechPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_AppnexusPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_FTPPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_OASPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_GDFPPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_FreewheelPulls"/> 
                <antcall target="run_ThirdPartyPulls"/> 
            </parallel>
            <parallel>
        <antcall target="run_PostData"/> 
                <antcall target="run_Sales"/> 
            </parallel>
            <parallel>
                <antcall target="run_Administration"/> 
                <antcall target="run_E2EPartner360"/> 
                <antcall target="run_Sales"/> 
                <antcall target="run_Finance"/> 
                <antcall target="run_Loaders"/> 
                <antcall target="run_Accounts"/> 
                <antcall target="run_Adops"/> 
            </parallel>
            <parallel>
                <antcall target="run_Alerts"/> 
                <antcall target="run_CustomFields"/> 
            </parallel>
            <antcall target="stop-selenium"/>
       </sequential>
    </target>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: your "buildfile" is just another question. Is it the same question?

Comment: I didn't post my build file other than this question . It might be  my colleague

Comment: the "other" queastion (previous link was wrong): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070175/selenium-grid-with-ant-sequential-parallel-execution/10087160#10087160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [try-catch](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html) from ant-contrib.

Example from the link:

```
<trycatch property="foo" reference="bar">
  <try>
    <fail>Tada!</fail>
  </try>

  <catch>
    <echo>In &lt;catch&gt;.</echo>
  </catch>

  <finally>
    <echo>In &lt;finally&gt;.</echo>
  </finally>
</trycatch>
```

If someting fails, you would just echo something (or do noting). The finally part works great if you need to make sure, that servers are shut down at the end, even if something fails hard in between.

Also setting `failonerror="false"` should make ant not to fail the build on errors.

Comment: Thanks, I will integrate and let u know .